# How to write Join query in eclipselink jpa

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I'm developing a server application in jpa eclipselink.
This is my query that works fine when I run it in my sqlworkbench:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `BuildingsTable` AS Buliding
    LEFT JOIN ServiceCallsTable AS Calls ON ( Calls.`buildingId` = Buliding.id ) 
    LEFT JOIN SchedualReviewsTable AS Review ON ( Review.`buildingId` = Buliding.id ) 
    WHERE Buliding.id =1
```

I have 3 table `BuildingsTable`, `ServiceCallsTable` and `SchedualReviewsTable`

The `buildingID` variable found in `Task` class

`ServiceCallsTable` and `SchedualReviewsTable` extends from `Task` class

This is my code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BuildingsTable")
public class Building extends Base{    
    @Column(name="description", nullable=false)
    private String description;
    @Column(name="address", nullable=false)
    private String address;
    @Column(name="constructYear", nullable=false)
    private int constructYear;  
    @Column(name="constructorName", nullable=false)
    private String constructorName;
    @Column(name="amountParkings", nullable=false)
    private int amountParkings;
    @Column(name="amountWarehouses", nullable=false)
    private int amountWarehouses;
    @Column(name="childrenId", nullable=false)

    // getters and setters
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Task extends Base{

    @Column(name="description", nullable=false)
    protected String description;
    @OneToOne
    @Column(name="buildingId", nullable=false)
    protected long buildingId;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ServiceCallsTable")
public class ServiceCall extends Task{
    @Column(name="reporterId", nullable=false)
    private long reporterId;
    @Column(name="imageDescription", nullable=false)
    private Text imageDescription;
    @Column(name="status", nullable=false)
    private int status;

    // getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SchedualReviewsTable")
public class SchedualReview extends Task{    
    @Column(name="pivotDate", nullable=false)
    private long pivotDate;
    @Column(name="lastReviewDate", nullable=false)
    private long lastReviewDate;
    @Column(name="reviewDaysFrequancy", nullable=false)
    private int reviewDaysFrequancy;
    @Column(name="buildingFacilityTypeIds", nullable=false)
    private List<Integer> buildingFacilityTypeIds;
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)

    // getters and setters
}
```

How can I write this query in JPA?

Comment: There are lots of references out there for JPQL. Tell us what you have tried, and what parts you haven't got working.

Comment: thank you for replay I want to get all serviceCalls and all SchedualReviews with specific buildingId every serviceCall and every schedualReview have long buildingId now in the client I have table show all tasks to user (task = serviceCall or SchedualReview) so I want to show all tasks in one table so I do not know how to write the query that will return my tasks

Comment: Your model is crap. A `OneToOne` relation is to an object of the RELATED TYPE (a Building perhaps), not a long! Consequently you cannot JOIN anywhere until you fix such things. This is shown in all JPA tutorials that I've ever seen.

Comment: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations